# Bootstrap table contents in a modal pop up

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have some formatting issues using bootstrap. 
I want to insert data in tabular form in modal-body. 
Is this possible? As i checked the sample, modal can only be used by using div tags.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Sure, you can use tables in modals!](http://jsfiddle.net/NYRby/1/):

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <table>
          <thead>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="table">
              <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>3</td>
                  <td>4</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: You may want to update the resources for the demo :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but I had to move my modal content to the top of the html body to get it to work correctly.

Comment: I tried these solutions, pasting it above/below/in the middle of the document and still didn't show up. No errors in the console, and the DOM elements show up when inspecting the page. As soon as I remove the table element it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this One**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container mt-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal">
            Add New User
        </button>
    </div>
    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="lead_id" class="col-form-label">ID:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lead_id">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="first_name" class="col-form-label">First Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="last_name" class="col-form-label">Last Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_nam"e>
                        </div>
                         
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```